# SSIS · Stop data flow if condition met

Tags: sql, ssis, package, etl

I need to stop the data flow and package if an Error Output has any rows.

In the example, none of the correct flow row may be processed (5983).

[image]

Comment: fail package on no lookup

Comment: but rows don't go to flat file error output, in that option.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how SSIS pipes work.  You could:

> 1. Load data to staging tables
> 2. Use a script task to determine if any rows went to error output table, if so then raise an error which stops package execution
> 3. If package didn't error the next step(s) to execute would be to transfer from staging to live tables